# Best practice for refactoring a python function to return a tuple, instead of a single variable?

Tags: python, tuples, return-value

I am refactoring a python function in a large codebase. Currently, it looks like:

```
def GetEvents(file_path):

    ...

    return events #a list of Event objects
```

A bunch of code depends on this function returning a list object already. However, I want to refactor it so it returns:

```
def GetEvents(file_path):

    ...

    return (events, event_header)
```

Where event_header is a little description of this group of events. However, this will badly break all code that currently expects a list, not a tuple to be returned. In any other language, I would pass the event_header by reference, but I do not think I can do that in Python. I could also declare another function, GetEventsAndHeader(), but that awkwardly duplicates functionality.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need this `event_header`, and if `GetEvents()` takes no arguments why do you even need the function, since it ought to be returning the same thing since it takes no arguments (in a perfect world).

Comment: It reads events from a file. Good eye. Updated question.

Comment: It really ought to take that file as an argument...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't absolutely need to return a tuple, just add an attribute to your returned list:

```
class EventList(list):
    pass


def GetEvents(file_path):

    ...

    events = EventList(events)
    events.event_header = some_header
    return events
```

Comment: This is a good idea. Implemented. It also means I don't have to have extra function names as per Martijn Pieters's suggestion. Yay.

Comment: Doing this has the nice feature that thinking this way won't cause me issues when I switch to editing other, non-Python code (since this works in all the languages I'm using and tuple-equivalents only work in some)

Answer (score 8):

*Rename* the function to `GetEventsAndHeader()`, and add a new function `GetEvents()`:

```
def GetEvents(*args, **kw):
    return GetEventsAndHeader(*args, **kw)[0]
```

or just bite the bullet and update all code that calls `GetEvents()` and adjust that code to either use the returnvalue indexed to `[0]` or make use of the headers as well.

Comment: I've done this (almost) exact thing so very many times.  It also contributes somewhat to code spaghetti, so when possible I have to agree with the 'bite the bullet' approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as noted, if this takes no arguments, then it probably shouldn't be a function. I'd add that it's probably part of an object, and if not, it should be.

That way, you can have:

```
class EventGroup(object):

     def GetEvents(): # note camelcase is not pep8 compliant
         return dat_list


     def EventGroupInfo():
         return some_info

     def fact_about_events1():
         return fact1

     def fact_about_events2():
         return fact2
```

I've used no-argument methods to parallel your code, but I don't necessarily recommend it.

An alternative design choice would be to return an object which respects the full list protocol, and carries metadata about the group of events also.